# How can I use jQueryUI datepicker onSelect but also the change event in my Backbone view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, datepicker

I've got a `DateSelectorView` that initializes jQuery UI datepicker, I've added the `onSelect` method which triggers a global event passing the date value. I need the global event to fire but I also need access to the value from within my view, having the 'change input' event in my view though doesn't get acknowledged as DateSelectorView onSelect traps it, can anyone recommend how I can fix this? Is there a way of triggering the global event then letting the DateSelectorView `onSelect` continue to whatever other events need it?

**JS**

```
App.Views.PersonView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    template: '.js-person-tmpl',

    events: {
        'change input': 'onSelect'
    },

    templateHelpers: function () {
        return {
            availableClasses: this.options.availableClasses.toJSON()
        }
    },

    initialize: function () {
        //console.log('PersonView::initialize', this.options, this.model.toJSON());
    },

    onRender: function() {
        this.dateSelector = new App.Views.DateSelectorView({
            el: this.$el.find('.js-date')
        });
    },

    onSelect: function() {
        console.log('date selected');

        // this.model.set('dateSelected', '');
    }
});

App.Views.DateSelectorView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    template: false,

    tagName: 'input',

    initialize: function() {
        //console.log('DateSelectorView::initialize');

        this.$el.datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
            altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            altField: '.js-date-hidden',
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            onSelect: function() {
                console.log('date:selected', this.value);

                Backbone.Events.trigger('date:selected', this.value);         
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/okmL8k8p/5/

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by Backbone events

```
App.Views.PersonView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
   initialize: function () {
      App.events.on("doSomething_event", this.onSelect);
   },
   onSelect: function(date) {
      console.log(date);
   }
});

App.Views.DateSelectorView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
     initialize: function() {
         this.$el.datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
            altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            altField: '.js-date-hidden',
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            onSelect: function() {
              App.events.trigger("doSomething_event", this.value);
            }
         });
     }
});

App.events = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

Hope this will helps you!